# Kendo Grid column width auto size

Tags: kendo-grid

I'm creating columns dynamically in Kendo Grid (don't know number of columns and columns name also). I'm unable to set size of the column width as pet text. Any one know how to do?

```
 $(".Grid").kendoGrid({
           dataSource: {
           data: $scope.data,
           pageSize: 5
           },
           sortable: true,
           pageable: {
              pageSizes: true,
              buttonCount: 5
              },
              scrollable: true,
             resizable: true
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

JS :

```
    var grid = $(".Grid").data("kendoGrid");

    var headerCols = grid.thead.parent().find("col");
    headerCols.eq(0).addClass("myCol0");
    headerCols.eq(1).addClass("myCol1");

    var bodyCols = grid.tbody.parent().find("col");
    bodyCols.eq(0).addClass("myCol0");
    bodyCols.eq(1).addClass("myCol1");
```

CSS:

```
.myCol0
{
    width: 100px;
}
.myCol1
{
    width: 200px;
}
```